# Upload file to ftp server using node js

Tags: node.js, ftp, ftp-client

I am trying to upload file from my local machine to ftp server using node js. Below is the code i have tried. i am getting error as "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND [https://owncloud.askgroup.co.in/remote.php/dav/files/jlotlikar/'](https://owncloud.askgroup.co.in/remote.php/dav/files/jlotlikar/%27).

```
 class FTPClient {
        constructor(host = 'localhost', port = 21, username = 'anonymous', password = 'guest', secure = false) {
            this.client = new ftp.Client();
            this.settings = {
                host: host,
                port: port,
                user: username,
                password: password,
                secure: secure
            };
        }
    
        upload(sourcePath, remotePath, permissions) {
            let self = this;
            (async () => {
                try {
                    let access = await self.client.access(self.settings);
                    let upload = await self.client.upload(fs.createReadStream(sourcePath), remotePath);
                    let permissions = await self.changePermissions(permissions.toString(), remotePath);
                } catch(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
                self.client.close();
            })();
        }
    
        close() {
            this.client.close();
        }
    
        changePermissions(perms, filepath) {
            let cmd = 'SITE CHMOD ' + perms + ' ' + filepath;
            return this.client.send(cmd, false);
        }
    }
    
    const client = new FTPClient('https://owncloud.askgroup.co.in/remote.php/dav/files/jlotlikar/', 443, 'jlotlikar', 'June@2020', false);

    client.upload('./cid.xml', 'HRMS_ExpenseReport/upload.xml', 443);
```

I am unable to connect to the server. and i am new to node and ftp transfer. can some body help me with connecting to ftp server and uploading a file through node js.